# JMSSerializerBundle and single table inheritance

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I use single table inheritance in doctrine and I wanted to change the way JMS serializes the entity according to the entity class.

In my single table inheritance, I have a type column which is used to map the discriminator.

My parent entity is BundleNamespace\Entity\Question.
When type is single_choice, my entity is BundleNamespace\Entity\Question\SingleChoiceQuestion.
When type is multiples_choice, my entity is BundleNamespace\Entity\Question\MultipleChoiceQuestion.

I configured jms in config.yml

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            exam:
                namespace_prefix: "BundleNamespace"
                path: "@BundleNamespace/Resources/config/serializer"
```

However when I create a yaml serializer file specific for each child entity, it does not seem to apply the specific configuration of each file :

- @BundleNamespace/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Question.SingleChoiceQuestion.yml
- @BundleNamespace/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Question.MultipleChoiceQuestion.yml

I would like to have a different serialization for each entity but I cannot seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me :

- define a serializer configuration for the parent entity in the single table inheritance and configure the properties to expose.
- for each child entity, use virtual properties to configure a custom serialization

With this configuration, all child entities share the common properties from the parent but can have specific properties (virtual in this case) according to their configuration.

It is not fully what I intended but It works. I would have liked to be able to hide specific properties of the parent in some child entities but I was not able to do it.